# Why am I getting "Instantiating mesh due to calling MeshFilter.mesh during edit mode" while not calling "MeshFilter.mesh"?

Tags: unity3d-editor

I have the following code to create a mesh from a collider shape. When I run it, I'm getting a `Instantiating mesh due to calling MeshFilter.mesh during edit mode. This will leak meshes. Please use MeshFilter.sharedMesh instead.` What I don't understand is *why* I'm getting this error. I am not using `MeshFilter.mesh` anywhere in the code. Is there a way to fix this?

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();

    if (GUILayout.Button("Create Mesh"))
    {
        Mesh mesh = createMesh.Collider.CreateMesh(false, false);
               // *** Error is marked on this line (not the line above or below) ***
        List<Vector3> Vertices = mesh.vertices.ToList();
        List<Vector2> UVs = new List<Vector2>();
        List<Vector3> Normals = new List<Vector3>();
        
        // Create UVs and normals for mesh front facing part
        foreach (Vector3 v in Vertices)
        {
            // Set UVs to vertex position to keep repeating texture undistorted
            UVs.Add(v);
            // Front facing polygons have same normal direction
            Normals.Add(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -1f));
        }

        mesh.vertices = Vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.uv = UVs.ToArray();
        mesh.normals = Normals.ToArray();
        
        createMesh.MeshTarget.sharedMesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

For clarification `createMesh` points to the actual `MonoBehaviour` script the editor script is for. `Collider` refers to a `Collider2D` component and `MeshTarget` refers to a `MeshFilter` component.